# How do I compare two columns in Excel to find if there is corresponding data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

How do I compare two Excel sheets to detect whether the data in column B of sheet 2 appears in column A of sheet 1?

Comment: a job for [vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)

Comment: `MATCH` might be faster than `VLOOKUP`.

Answer (score 4):

use Match() built-in function

for example

if your data looks like this

```
  | Column A   | Column B
----------------------------
1 |  number1   |  number1
2 |  number2   |  number7
3 |  number3   |
4 |  number4   |
5 |  number5   |
```

then stick the below formula in column C

```
=MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$5,0)
```

and if there is a match you will get `1` in column C, if there is no match an `#N/A`. You can wrap around the match function to display a custom message. But I think the above answers your question.